# Multiple queries in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060493/sql-case-statement)

Hi Frdz, i have created a stored proc and i put three queries in stored proc with inputvariable @EtlLoadId = 0 and i get three different windows for each query under result tab. is there any chance i can get results from the stored proc (results of three queries) as only one window and results one below another under result tab ?

```
IF (SELECT EtlLoadId 
 FROM  ssislogs.audit.processcontrol 
 WHERE SubjectArea = 'UaqaFacetsImp') > 0
SELECT pc.SrcFileName + ' - '+  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), pc.[RecordCount] ) AS FacetsImpCount
 FROM  ssislogs.audit.processcontrol pc left outer join
 Uaqa.LettersAndCardsExports lc
on pc.etlloadid = lc.etlloadid
  WHERE pc.subjectarea = 'UaqaFacetsImp'
ELSE
SELECT 'No input file' AS FacetsImpCount

SELECT pc.subjectarea AS FacetsRjctFile
FROM  ssislogs.audit.processcontrol pc left outer join
Uaqa.LettersAndCardsExports lc
on pc.etlloadid = lc.etlloadid
  WHERE pc.subjectarea = 'UaqaFacetsRjct'

SELECT pc.subjectarea AS FacetsPvsFile
FROM  ssislogs.audit.processcontrol pc left outer join
Uaqa.LettersAndCardsExports lc
on pc.etlloadid = lc.etlloadid
  WHERE pc.subjectarea = 'UaqaFacetsPvs'
```

Thanks

Comment: @OMG Ponies: yes, asking the same thing. "How do I get one result"

Comment: @gbn - Look at the link provided.  Use a UNION in your query if you want to get one table of results.  You will need to pay attention to data types and use CAST/CONVERT where necessary.

Comment: @Vinnie: not quite sure why you mention that... if you look at my profile *and* exact timings of my answer (first) and comment (second)

Comment: Sorry, I meant put @Neoooo but referenced your name. I meant to concur with what you and OMG Ponies posted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server based on some clues, use text mode, not grid mode in SSMS

Before executing:

- Control+T = text mode
- Control+G = grid mode

It makes no different to the actual execution: 3 result sets returned.

Answer (score 0):

Set your query results window to view as text and all three will be together.